# Can't perform a request on Laravel with 3 tables

Tags: database, laravel

I began laravel one week ago, and today I decided to properly use eloquent.

So I will explain you my problem, and if you are wondering, yes I already looked for a solution on topics, google .. 
I'm on this problem for about 8 hours .. Start to get tired.
Well, I created 3 databases (using mgrations, and creating relations)

- Tags [id; name]
- Users [id, its not important]
- TagsRelationUsers [id, user_id, tag_id]

So, I just want to make a request that gives me the all the tags name related with a user, in the tagsRelationUsers table, by just having the user_id.

In my case, a user can have an infinite amount of tags, and a tag can have an infinitee amount of users, that's why I created a table called TagsRelationUsers.

```
class User extends Authenticatable

public function tagsRelationsUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TagRelationUser');
}
```

.

```
class Tag extends Model

public function tagsRelationsUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\TagRelationUser');
}
```

If you can help me, this will be super cool :). Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things a bit wrong here,

1. The relation method is called incorrectly. (for many to many relationships).
2. Laravel guesses the pivot table name from the related tables. Sorting them in alphabetical order using the singular form of the table name and joining them up using '_' (so in your case tag_user). But you are using TagsRelationUsers as the pivot table so you need to specify that explicitly.

Guessing your pivot table name is TagsRelationUsers.

Try this.

```
class User extends Authenticatable

public function tagsRelationsUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tag', 'TagsRelationUsers', 'tag_id', 'user_id');
}

class Tag extends Model

public function tagsRelationsUsers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User', 'TagsRelationUsers', 'user_id', 'tag_id');
}
```